# mysqli update not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
        $sql3 = "SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE order_code = '$order_code'";
        $result3 = $conn->query($sql3) or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
        $order_id = $row['order_id'];       

        $deliv_date = date('Y-m-d');

        $sql = "UPDATE orders SET deliv_date = $deliv_date
                        WHERE order_id = $order_id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql) or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");



        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO invoice VALUES (0,'$order_code','$deliv_date','','$order_id')";

        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1) or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");
```

The above is the code that I am using. The insert on the last line works correctly and picks up the correct $order_code, $deliv_date and $order_id. There is no error on the update, but the field "deliv_date" is never set to $deliv_date.  I just can't see what the problem is logically. Can anyone spot it? I have been going up the wall.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your date in quotes:

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET deliv_date = $deliv_date
                    WHERE order_id = $order_id";
```

should be

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET deliv_date = '$deliv_date' <-- HERE
                    WHERE order_id = $order_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET deliv_date = $deliv_date
                        WHERE order_id = $order_id";
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET deliv_date = '$deliv_date'
                        WHERE order_id = $order_id";
```